# Sending data to a server using remix run

Tags: remix.run

I am having issues sending data to a server using remix run - I'm not sure I fully understand how useAction data works.  I understand how the useLoaderData functions work but when you are trying to send data to a server I get errors.

What I want to do is send a post request to my server when I click a button - if I try and call create cart in the handleCLick event it says that createCart is not a function when it is

```
const submit = useSubmit()

 function action({ request }) {
  is this where i do my POST api call?

}

async function handleClick(event) {
    await createCart(id, amount)
  }
```

Cant seem to find any documentation which tells you how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Hit send too early

With Remix, actions always run on the server. It is the method that Remix will call when you POST to a route.

```js
// route.tsx

import { json, type ActionArgs, type LoaderArgs } from '@remix-run/node'
import { Form, useActionData, useLoaderData, useSubmit } from '@remix-run/react'
import { createCart } from '~/models/cart.server' // your app code
import { getUserId } from '~/models/user.server' 

// loader is called on GET
export const loader = async ({request}: LoaderArgs) => {
  // get current user id
  const id = await getUserId(request)
  // return
  return json({ id })
}

// action is called on POST
export const action = async ({request}: ActionArgs) => {
  // get the form data from the POST
  const formData = await request.formData()
  // get the values from form data converting types
  const id = Number(formData.get('id'))
  const amount = Number(formData.get('amount'))
  // call function on back end to create cart
  const cart = await createCart(id, amount)
  // return the cart to the client
  return json({ cart })
}

// this is your UI component
export default function Cart() {
  // useLoaderData is simply returning the data from loader, it has already
  // been fetched before component is rendered. It does NOT do the actual 
  // fetch, Remix fetches for you
  const { id } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>()
  // useActionData returns result from action (it's undefined until
  // action has been called so guard against that for destructuring
  const { cart } = useActionData<typeof action>() ?? {}
  // Remix handles Form submit automatically so you don't really
  // need the useSubmit hook
  const submit = useSubmit()
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    submit(e.target.form)
  }
  return (
    <Form method="post">
      {/* hidden form field to pass back user id *}
      <input type="hidden" name="id"/>
      <input type="number" name="amount"/>
      {/* Remix will automatically call submit when you click button *}
      <button>Create Cart</button>
      {/* show returned cart data from action */}
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(cart, null, 2)}</pre>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation makes much more sense now!

Comment: can you include your imports please?

Comment: Thanks @Kiliman .. the guarding against useActionData returning null when action not run was a life saver!

Comment: If I don't want to using Form, how can I trigger push data to action function?

Comment: @huykon225 You can use fetcher.post `useFetcher` to submit data to your action. https://remix.run/docs/en/1.19.3/hooks/use-fetcher