# how to use both useLoaderData() and useActionData() in the same component

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I am building my app with remix.run.

I have a route for a component that has a loader function to load data when the component loads.
The component also has a form nested within it which requires validation and therefore requires an action function.
Therefore, the component has both useLoaderData() and a conflicting useActionData()

Any ideas on how do you overcome this without submitting the form to a non route component and using sessions and a redirect?

Comment: You can use both in your route component. `useActionData` only has data returned from the action, otherwise, it returns `null`. Can you update your question with sample code?

Comment: Thanks Kiliman. I've found the answer and as you've pointed out you can use both in the component - what I needed to do was prevent an error if useActionData doesn't get loaded. eg. const { action_data } = useActionData() ?? {};

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try to use useEffect and useState hooks in your component. In the useEffect hook, you can call the useLoaderData function to load the data, and in the useState hook, you can store the form data and the action function.

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
const [error, setError] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  useLoaderData();
}, []);

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  setError(null);
  try {
    await useActionData(formData);
  } catch (err) {
    setError(err.message);
  }
};

return (
  <>
    {error && <p>{error}</p>}
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {/* your form inputs */}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think the answer is as simple as adding a conditional for useActionData(), to prevent it trying to destructure when the action function hasn't been called... eg. const { errors, values } = useActionData() ?? {};    ...I got this from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72516312/sending-data-to-a-server-using-remix-run